# Get checkbox values via REST API - SharePoint 2013

Tags: rest

I have a status field choice with multiple values.
How can i get /retrieve these values via rest api

tried :

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
alert(data.d.results[i].Status);
}
```

I have attached the data im getting from rest.How to get into the collection?

Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `data.d.results[i].Status[0]?`

Comment: just got and was about to post it. Thanks alot. Is the anywhere online with a proper documentation with sharepoint 2013 rest api?

Comment: You can check Odata/JSON Parsing. That is the standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop using

```
    $.each(data.d.results, function (index, task) {
        for(i = 0; i < task.Status.length; i++)
            alert(task.Status[i]);
    });
```